# in OCI Java sdk, how to retrieve the autonomous database username and apex workspace restful url?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-autonomous-db, oci-java-sdk

I am using the Oracle autonomous cloud database and creating a couple of database username with ethe restful web enabled, along with the database schema, i also create some Apex workspace based on these database schema.

my question is how to retrieve the restful endpoint URL of these database username, Apex Workspace via the OCI Java SDK.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this REST API?

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/database/20160918/AutonomousDatabase/

These 2 attributes apexDetails and connectionStrings could help you get the info you need.

Thanks.